# How do we know that we get all the soltuions of Null(A)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am wondering why the algorithm to find the spanning vectors of the nullspace gives us all the solutions of the nullspace of a matrix, how do we know that there may not be any more? I will show the algoritm below with a matrix.

Assume that

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -2 &0&-1 &3 \newline
    0&0 &1&2 &-2
    \end{bmatrix}.$$

Then we get the equations

$$x_1-2x_2-x_4+3x_5=0$$
$$x_3+2x_4-2x_5=0$$

And we get that the solutions are $s(2,1,0,0,0)+t(1,0,-2,1,0)+u(-3,0,2,0,1), s,t,u\in \mathbb{R}.$

I can see why the solutions we found using this algorithm must be in Null(A). But how do we show that all solutions are of this form? I can't use the fact that the dimension of the nullspace equals the number of free variables, because this fact relies on the fact that the nullspace is spanned by the 3 vectors above.

Comment: The quick answer above is that the range of $A$ has dimension $2$ (note that $(0,1), (1,0)$ are in the range, for example), so the rank nullity theorem tells us that the kernel must have dimension $3$.

Comment: We have $x \in$ Null$(A) \Leftrightarrow Ax=0$ - that is the definition. And $Ax=0$ is equivalent to the two equations that you wrote down, because that are just the two rows of the matrix-vector equation $Ax=0$, so the answer is basically "we get all solutions for the Null-Space by definition of the Null-Space"

Comment: If there is a solution not of that form, then there is another vector (other than $(2,1,0,0,0);(1,0,-2,1,0);(-3,0,2,0,1)$) which is included in the basis of the null space which includes those 3 vectors. Therefore the nullspace has more than 3 dimensions, contradiction.

Comment: The long answer (probably not applicable here) is that in numerical practice it can be difficult to tell due to numerical noise.